# Why can't I control the selection of items in the drop down list using the arrow keys?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I try to use down and up arrow to select item in DropDownList but it doesn't work.
Do you know why?

Thanks for your help

Comment: In my experience it has worked in the past.  Can you show some code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Problem is solved : my custom window type (extend tilewindow) make this mistake!

Comment: You should post this as a formal answer with details.  That'll help future users of the site who have similar problem.